# saveMyProfile evaluates false 2 times

Tags: java

My saveMyProfile method comes up false 2 times and I can't figure out how to get to true. Thank you for your time.

```
import student.web.SharedPersistentMap; 
import student.*;
import java.util.*;
```

Creates a SharedPersistentMap for the User Profiles.

```
public class ProfileViewer
extends UserProfile
{
```

Instance/static variables

```
private SharedPersistentMap < UserProfile > profiles;
private UserProfile myProfile;
```

Constructor

Creates a new ProfileViewer object with the SharedPersistentMap.

```
public ProfileViewer()
{
    profiles = new SharedPersistentMap < UserProfile > (UserProfile.class);
}
```

Methods

Sets a new profile name.

@param newMyProfile The new profile name.

```
public void setMyProfile (UserProfile newMyProfile)
{
    myProfile = newMyProfile;
}
```

Gets the profile name.

@return myProfile;

```
public UserProfile getMyProfile()
{
    return myProfile;
}
```

Creates new

@param username The username.

```
public void createNewMyProfile (String username)
{
    if ((username != null) && !(username.isEmpty()))
    {
        UserProfile userProf2 = new UserProfile();
        userProf2.setName(username);
        setMyProfile(userProf2);
    }
}
```

Saves the new profile.

```
public void saveMyProfile ()
{
    if (((myProfile != null) && (myProfile.getName() != null)) 
        && (myProfile.getName().isEmpty()))
    {
        profiles.put(myProfile.getName(), myProfile);
    }
}
```

Loads the desired profile.

@param username The username.

```
public void loadMyProfile (String username)
{
    if ((username != null) && !(username.equals("")))
    {
        myProfile = profiles.get(username);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your disjointed code is close to impossible to follow. How about posting the code in one single unit, as we're used to seeing it? How about taking just a little time to type in a few sentences giving more details of your program and your problem. The rule to follow is to put as much effort into asking your question as you want someone to put in answering it.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void saveMyProfile ()
{
    if (((myProfile != null) && (myProfile.getName() != null)) 
        && (myProfile.getName().isEmpty()))
    {
        profiles.put(myProfile.getName(), myProfile);
    }
}
```

I think your problem is you are checking your `myProfile.getName().isEmpty()` as added condition

I think what you would like to do is `(!myProfile.getName().isEmpty())` add not (!) :)